# How to Break Line in MathJax using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, mathjax

I'm using `MathJax` I can't able to break the new line. 
I am already tried using `<br/>` , `\n`and `\\` but its not works for me.

```
const blockFormula = `x =√(t )   \\
\\mathrm{V}=\\frac{d x}{d t}=\\frac{1}{2} t^{\\frac{-1}{2}}`;
```

[MathJax Doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mathjax) version **1.0.1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line-breaks you show are for HTML and for regular Latex. MathJax only treats the MATH MODE PART of Latex, not all of Latex so you need to accomplish line-breaks math mode style. You basically have at least 3 options:

- Use the math mode `gather` environment:

  ```
  <MathJax>
      {
        `$$\\begin{gather}
              x =√(t ) \\\\ 
              \\mathrm{V}=\\frac{d x}{d t}=\\frac{1}{2} t^{\\frac{-1}{2}} \\\\
        \\end{gather}$$`
      }
  </MathJax>
  ```
- Use the math mode `align` environment if you also want to align the rows:

  ```
  <MathJax>
      {
        `$$\\begin{align}
              x &=√(t ) \\\\ 
              \\mathrm{V}=\\frac{d x}{d t}&=\\frac{1}{2} t^{\\frac{-1}{2}} \\\\
        \\end{align}$$`
      }
  </MathJax>
  ```
- Since you're doing this in React with HTML, you can also add the different rows to different HTML / React components to accomplish what you want:

  ```
  <MathJax>{`$$x =√(t )$$`}</MathJax>
  <MathJax>{`$$\\mathrm{V}=\\frac{d x}{d t}=\\frac{1}{2} t^{\\frac{-1}{2}}$$`}</MathJax>
  ```

There are probably more ways too.

I took the liberty of using my own [`better-react-mathjax`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-react-mathjax) in the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/user-example-7-2btsz) that I prepared for you, showing all these options using both display math and inline math, but it should work the same in all libraries that correctly uses MathJax with React.

Answer (score -1):

```
config = {
           CommonHTML: { linebreaks: { automatic: true } },
           showMathMenu: false,
           'HTML-CSS': {
               linebreaks: { automatic: true, width: 'container' },
               scale: 150
           }
        };
```